# Is there a way to have mapping populate a property of the model asynchronously and have the view update automatically?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I'm trying to load the values for a model's property through AJAX, but on AJAX' completion the view is not updated.

I'm using knockout 2.0.0 and knockout mapping 2.0.3.

**jsFiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/rsfTy/

**HTML:**

```html
<p>Code: <span data-bind="text: item.code"></span></p>
<p>Value: <span data-bind="text: item.value"></span></p>
```

**JavaScript:**

```js
var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.item = ko.mapping.fromJS({ "code": "123" });

    self.load = function () {
        jQuery.ajax({
            "success": function () {
                ko.mapping.fromJS({ "value": "abc" }, {}, self.item);
            },
            "url": "/echo/json"
        });            
    };

    self.load();
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

In this example the value of `item.code` is displayed because it's defined when the viewmodel is initialized, but the value of `item.value` is never shown because is filled in asynchronously.

I've already tried the various permutations of `ko.observable` and `ko.mapping.fromJS`, both for property initialization and update, to no avail.

I would like to avoid - if possible - to initialize all the `item`'s properties by hand.

I also know I can move `ko.applyBindings` inside the `success` of the AJAX call, but I have more than one property like this and to do it I'd have to implement a queue system, which is an overkill.

What am I doing wrong? What's the correct way do it?

Answer (score 3):

When you do the initial mapping, there will be no "value" observable for the UI to bind against.  So, when you do the update via the mapping plugin, it will create the "value" observable, but it is too late (as the UI has already been through binding).

If you initialize it like: `self.item = ko.mapping.fromJS({ "code": "123", "value": "" });` then it will work properly.

Comment: That makes sense, but I'm fetching ~20 fields from the database and having to initialize all of them by hand beforehand is kind of ugly; is it the only way to do it?

Comment: I came across the same problem. I created a default model which is populated from the server, then it is serialized on the client. Then I create a default view model using ko.mapping.fromJS based on the default model.

Comment: You either have to have a blank model to initialize it or wait to call ko.applyBindings on your UI until after you have received some data from the server.